# my game crashes when i try to fire bullets in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game which I use the left and right keys to move the spaceship and the space bar to fire bullets, but when pressing the space bar the game crashes.
I can't figure out what's causing it.

here's my code:

https://github.com/Eid-alhamali/Eid/tree/master/alien_invasion

here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/eidha/OneDrive/سطح المكتب/alien_invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 32, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "c:/Users/eidha/OneDrive/سطح المكتب/alien_invasion/alien_invasion.py", line 27, in run_game
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
  File "c:\Users\eidha\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 34, in 
check_events
    check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
  File "c:\Users\eidha\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 17, in 
check_keydown_events
    new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
  File "C:\Users\eidha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\eidha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not Settings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` function in Bullet is capitalized, meaning it isn't overriding the default Sprite group. Because of this you are actually calling the Sprite `__init__` function, and you are passing ai_settings (a `Settings` object) as the `*groups` parameter.

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A Class To Manage Bullets Fired From The Ship"""
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship): # Notice lowercase
        super().__init__()
        ...
```